# How to display .tiff images in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tiff

I want to display .tiff images coming from server in my native iphone application. Is it possible to display .tiff images in native iphone application?
I am trying to solve this problem since 2 hrs with no success. I searched the net for nearly 2 hrs with no solution to this problem.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem...

Any sample code will be very helpful...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it says that the tiff format is supported by the `UIImage` class so you can load it in one of those and put it into an `UIImageView`. Have you already tried this? If the answer is yes, post some code

Comment: i have tried this.. the image is coming from the server in the tiff format. plz help me....

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can display tiff images coming from the server. You can load these images into WebView or `UIImageView`. What you need to do is :

You need to encode the data which comes from the server.After encoding the data, you need to add it inside the WebView. Example :

```
NSMutableData *recievedData; // the data coming from the server

......

NSString *str = [receivedData base64Encoding]; //my base64Encoding function

NSData *new_data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:str]; my function

UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageWithData:new_data];

[image_view setImage:image2];

[web_view loadData:new_data MIMEType:@"image.tiff" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
```